Syntax error in OpenModelica not allowing to leave current text mode (to check other text or menu bar)
OpenModelica has an automatic error-checking feature in textual mode. If the syntax of the model has an error (most times because it is work in progress), this does not allow to go check another code or to access the top menu bar.
To my understanding this should be allowed, because as you develop a model, it is quite common that you need to see another code (for example to a connecting component or an inherited component etc.). It makes my workflow less productive. I am ok with keeping errors inside the model, and "discover them" once I finish development and want to compile/simulate.
Any idea how to disable or workaround this feature?
I went through the user guide, forums and the options - but I did not find any solution.

The current design of the OpenModelica GUI requires that the models are valid. This is needed for the diagrams.
Right now there is no workaround. Please follow https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/13039

Thanks Adeel for the information. Is there any plan to allow this in the future?

1.25 release is scheduled for next month. It is not possible to have this feature in that release. I will try to include it in 1.26 which might come out in summer next year. For now, I added the 2.0 milestone to the issue.

Thank you so much! This will be very useful!
